# Light Strip with ESP8266 and ZigBee for HUE Bridge

Tags: arduino, esp8266, zigbee

I currently have an ESP8266, which controlls my WS2812b light strip.

I want to add it to my current Hue  setup(1 Bridge, 4 Lamps). I know that I'll need a ZigBee module of some sort. Are there any I can add to my esp and then decide if I want to use the commands the hue sent me or if I want to manually control the light strip?

Do you know of any compatible ZigBee devices?

Comment: Please improve your question. What is "current Hue setup"? When you said that _"I'll a ZigBee module"_, is there a missing verb here?  It seems that you're looking for  some kind of adapter to make the connection of ESP8266 to a Zigbee module. And this is not a forum for ask for commercial products recommendation.

Comment: The question is very clear, he owns an existing Hue Bridge and he wants to use an ESP8266 to control a WS2812b light strip, he wants it to be recognized as a ZigBee Light Link device.